# WebView always return empty string when evaluateJavascript on xpath

Tags: android, xpath, kotlin, webview

webView setup:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

load URL. I can see the page loaded. Then:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("document.evaluate('/html/body/h1', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue.toString()", {
    Log.i("Test",it)
})
```

The log always prints "".

document.evaluate('/html/body/h1', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue.toString() works in chrome console.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of evaluateJavaScript are:

```
evaluateJavaScript(String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)
```

You don't have the Call back function and the onReceiveValue(String value) function which is generated by the ValueCallback parameter. Try this:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("document.evaluate('/html/body/h1', document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue.toString()", new ValueCallback<String>(){
    @Override
    public void OnReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
    }
});
```